# If $W$ is a random variable following Gompertz distribution with force of mortality $\lambda(w) = a(1.1)^w$ and $\Pr(63 < W < 64) = 0.01$, find $a$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose that the length $W$ of a human life does follow the Gompertz distribution with force of mortality $\lambda(w) = a(1.1)^w$ and $\Pr(63 < W < 64) = 0.01.$

I need to determine the constant $a > 0$ that makes this probability true.

Using the CDF $G(w)$ of $W$, which is defined in terms of $\lambda(w)$,

$$G(w) = 1-\exp\bigg(\frac{a}{\ln(1.1)} - \frac{a(1.1)^w}{\ln(1.1)}\bigg)$$

for $w \geq 0$, I have

$$G(64) - G(63) = 0.01$$

which after simplification produces the equation

$$\exp\bigg[a\bigg(\frac{1-(1.1)^{63}}{\ln(1.1)}\bigg)\bigg] - \exp\bigg[\bigg(a\bigg(\frac{1-(1.1)^{64}}{\ln(1.1)}\bigg)\bigg] = 0.01 \tag{1}$$

However, I have no clue how to solve for $a$ analytically, so I have two questions:

1. Is it even possible to solve $(1)$ analytically?
2. What kind of numerical methods can be used to approximate $a$?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can get an approximate solution by finding the pdf at $w=\frac{63+64}{2}$ and setting it equal to $\frac{0.01}{64-63}$, though even then you may need to use the Lambert $W$ function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no analytical solution for the general case of equations such as $e^{\alpha a}-e^{\beta a}=\gamma$ and numerical methods should be used.

Looking at the question, I suppose that $a$ would be quite small.

Consider the function
$$f(a)=G(64)-G(63)-\frac 1 {100}$$

Compute the derivative  and set it equal to $0$; the solution is $a_*\approx 0.000224679$ and, For this value, the function  is positive and the second derivative test shows that this is a maximum. So there are two solutions  such that $0 < a_1 <  a_* < a_2$.

The first one can be approximated using a Taylor expansion built around $a=0$; this would give
$$a_1\approx \frac{\log (b)}{100 (b-1) b^{63}} \qquad \text{with} \qquad b=1.1$$ that is to say $a_1\approx 0.0000235180$ while a rigorous calculation (using Newton method would give $a_1\approx 0.0000264595$.

For the second root, start Newton method using, say, $a_0=2a_*$ and the iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & a_n \\
 0 & 0.0004493583 \\
 1 & 0.0007253602 \\
 2 & 0.0007850377 \\
 3 & 0.0007900188 \\
 4 & 0.0007900521 
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Concerning the first root, we can make **one** single iteration of higher order $n$ methods (starting with $a_0=0$) and get as estimates of the solution
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & a_{(n)} &  \text{method} \\
 2 & 0.0000235180  & \text{Newton} \\
 3 & 0.0000259816  & \text{Halley}\\
 4 & 0.0000263686  & \text{Householder}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: How were you able to deduce that two solutions exist? Also l, I was thinking about using Newton’s method, but I didn’t know where I should start the algorithm, so how did you determine where to begin?